# Why am I still gaining infamy even though I am wearing NCR armor?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Am I misunderstanding how faction armor works?  It's my understanding that while you are wearing faction armor, NCR for example and attack another faction, Legion, in this case, I would not gain infamy.

To test that, I donned some NCR armor and fought some random Legionares.  After a few of them went down, my faction rep turned to hated.  I figured that waiting a little while and removing the armor would cause me to not be villified.  However, I'm still hated.

When do I get reputation changes while wearing faction armor?  I did have Boone with me, do companions affect rep gains as well?

Comment: There are some enemies, like the Mongrels and the higher-ranked legionaries, that can see through disguises. If there were any of these among the group you fought, that could explain your loss of reputation. I have initially assumed you still gained permanent infamy while disguised, but this page contradicts that: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_reputations#Notes

Comment: That may be why then.  I was assaulting the Legion camp near Novac where you rescue some NCR troops.  There probably was a high ranking officer there who saw.  If I am not seen (not detected) killing a Legion troop, do I still gain the infamy simply because they are nearby?

Comment: Pretty sure you don't, as long as it's a stealth kill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule of shooting stuff while avoiding faction loss: If you're not crouching, the faction will know that you were the one who shot their soldiers. It's not clear whether you did this, so I'll just throw that in.

Faction armor cannot be used to perform actions as if you belonged to that faction; it will only affect how factions react to your presence. Say that you were to put on Any-Faction Armor, and then walk up to a regular Any-Faction Soldier. They wouldn't catch your bluff, but if you were to shoot them (while not crouching), they would know that you did not belong to the Any-Faction, and consequently tick down your standing with the Any-Faction.

As for companions, I usually avoid them as they have a tendency to go guns blazing when you initiate a battle, thus reducing your chances of successfully avoiding faction-standing penalties.

Answer (score 1):

The introduction the game gives to faction armor specifically says that your actions while wearing faction armor still count against you. Faction armor only brings your status with a faction to neutral temporarily, it doesn't allow you to negate infamy entirely.

Boone always causes members of the Legion to attack on sight. So if you wear the armor but make Boone wait you could more then likely do what you were trying do without gaining infamy but the second you lose the armor, they will attack.

Answer (score 0):

The faction armour doesn't work like that in my opinion, it influences the factions default behaviour towards you (wearing friendly clothing means they typically won't attack on sight), but doesn't actually impact the effect of your actions. If you want to kill the Legion without earning infamy you will have to use stealth (since they only hate you if you're seen attacking them).